# Inserting a Binary file in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I want to store a native binary file into the DB having the column datatype as 'image', in SQL Server 2000, through SQL Query.

I have found the solution for the case of 2005, thet is using the OPENROWSET and BULK. The solution as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp](
    [name] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [blob] [image] NULL
)

INSERT INTO TEMP(ID,NAME, BDATA) 
SELECT 3, 'jmaniac',* 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\J.JPG',SINGLE_BLOB)  RA
```

P.S: Alias is must in the end.

Can you please help me out in constructing the SQL or TSQL Query for performing that operation?

Thanks a Bunch in Advance :)

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful if you posted the full solution you found for SQL Server 2005.

You won't be able to use `OPENROWSET` for SQL 2000.

Details on how to import a File in to a Image column can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175795.aspx)